# Custom Binding<String> doesn't work in iOS 16

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, ios16, ios17

I made 2 custom `Binding<String>` from the `priceRange` property.
Everything works correctly in my opinion, but when entering a value in iOS 16 nothing happens, TextField does not accept a value from the keyboard:

```swift
struct AnotherQuestion: View {
    @State
    private var priceRange: ClosedRange<Float> = 500 ... 1000

    private var lowerPriceBinding: Binding<String> {
        Binding {
            let lowerValue = Int(priceRange.lowerBound)
            guard lowerValue != 500 else { return "" }
            return "\(lowerValue)"
        } set: { newValue in
            guard let lowerBound = Float(newValue),
                  500 ... 1000 ~= lowerBound,
                  lowerBound <= priceRange.upperBound else { return }

            priceRange = lowerBound ... priceRange.upperBound
        }
    }

    private var upperPriceBinding: Binding<String> {
        Binding {
            let maxValue = Int(priceRange.upperBound)
            guard maxValue != 1000 else { return "" }
            return "\(maxValue)"
        } set: { newValue in
            guard let upperBound = Float(newValue),
                  upperBound <= 1000,
                  priceRange.lowerBound <= upperBound else { return }

            priceRange = priceRange.lowerBound ... upperBound
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Lower: \(priceRange.lowerBound, specifier: "%0.f")")
                Spacer()
                Text("Upper: \(priceRange.upperBound, specifier: "%0.f")")
                Spacer()
            }

            HStack {
                TextField("Min price", text: lowerPriceBinding)
                TextField("Max price", text: upperPriceBinding)
            }
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

#Preview {
    AnotherQuestion()
}
```

The same code works fine in iOS 17, i.e. the value can be typed from the keyboard.
Main question is why this binding doesn't work in iOS 16 ?

Comment: No offence but when I played around with your code in iOS17 I found so many strange things with your code that you might want to focus on that instead. Why are you even using Float when all one can enter is integer values, the real range is actually 501...999 because of how the code behaves, values aren't reset properly when there's an out of range error so changing one field can update both Text fields ...

Comment: IMO this is such a hacky way... why not define a custom `Formatter` instead, and pass it to `TextField(..., formatter: YourCustomFormater)`?

Comment: @timbretimbre 
it's just a piece of code.
In reality, I'm using a Range Slider that requires me to pass a Binding<ClosedRange<Float>> and x2 TextField

Comment: There are very rare cases, mostly workarounds due to SwiftUI limitations that would require binding defined like you did. Think about it: you basically not using anything that Binding provides, just making it look like one to pass compilation. So I still think there's a better solution. Try to make your question more specific so people can help you solve the actual issue you have.

Comment: I agree with you, but the main question is why this binding doesn't work in iOS 16 ?

Comment: May be I am not good enough in Swift, but what is supposed to do the expression : « 500 ... 1000 ~= lowerBound» ? Also why using != and not > or < when testing bound value ?

Comment: @PtitXav `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range/~=(\_:_:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding is working fine: but the get function returns an empty string, since no single digit (or character) is in your range.

TextField in iOS16.4 is overwriting the input with the binding value after every input. It seems that this behavior was changed in iOS17 to rewrite the value only after submitting.

As to why this behavior changed, I can't find any official documentation. It might have to do with [UIKit text changes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10058/), or [one of many other changes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10148/).

In any case, this is not really a bug but rather a change in implementation. (The behaviour in iOS16.4 is in fact more aligned with my expectations of this code.) Reading the comments, I agree that this code is hacky, and would recommend you rewrite it to work -with- SwiftUI rather than against it, e.g using [the Formatter initializer for TextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:formatter:)-4013v), which per documentation implements the sort of behaviour you expect. (And if there is a different issue affecting the slider in your use case, please open a question concerning that).

Comment: In iOS 17 and 17.2 (Simulator) I can observe, that the binding's setter will be called with every change of the text field's string with the current value. So far, that's OK. However, there's a difference in the behaviour, when the setter attempts to change that exact same string buffer: in iOS 16 the changed string will be reflected in the TextField 2 out of 3 times. In iOS 17, it has no effect. Call this a bug. :)